# ejabberd "high" number of aborted transactions - should I be concerned?

Tags: transactions, ejabberd, mnesia

I'm new to ejabberd and didn't find any documentation on this. I have the following statistics of my just installed ejabberd server:

```
Transactions Committed: 83
Transactions Aborted:   136
Transactions Restarted: 0
Transactions Logged:    2
```

I feel the number of aborted transactions is a bit high for a server that is just running for about a day. What does this number indicate? Do I have to improve something?

Usually, high number of aborted transactions mean that there are issues with the database writing the data. What does it mean here?

I'm using the default database, which is Mnesia if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using the default database, which is Mnesia if I understand correctly.

Right, if you didn't change the database configuration, it's Mnesia by default, and that is an internal database that runs inside the same erlang application that ejabberd.

If there were serious problems, error messages would appear in the ejabberd log files. In my small 1-user test server I have a pair of aborted transactions, so that isn't uncommon. In another mid-size server I see:

```
Transactions Committed: 28,204,480
Transactions Aborted:   69
Transactions Restarted: 4,228
Transactions Logged:    492,886
```

So you are right, that your number looks high. You can set loglevel in ejabberd configuration file to a higher value, and take a look to error or warning messages searching for some clue.

Comment: Thanks! As I found out, the number of aborts seems to be stable now and not growing. So I guess the aborts in the statistics are from the time when I was making changes to the config and made some mistakes :)